# Jquery UI datepicker closes on next().focus()

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to select subsequently two dates from a datepicker widget, then I want to focus on the second when the first one is selected.
I set it up like this:

```
<input type="text" class="date" id="fromDate" name="fromDate"/>
<input type="text" class="date" id="toDate" name="toDate"/>

$("input.date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
        $(this).next(".date").focus();
    }
});
```

But when I select the first date the second opens then closes the window... why?

I saw that with onClose event works, but I don't want to open the other date if the first one is not selected...

Please try it from fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld98p/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's interesting. Even calling the [show()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show) method of the datepicker widget results in the same behavior.

It looks like the `onSelect` callback is invoked in a pretty complex situation, events-wise, and triggering `focus` or force-showing the popup from the callback itself cannot be relied upon.

However, triggering `focus` from a slightly delayed function appears to work:

```
$("input.date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
            $(this).next(".date").focus();
        }, this), 10);
    }
});
```

You can test it in [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld98p/5/).

Comment: This works... however it is a bit strange to use a timer to open a datepiker :-)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works although it's not very clean for the code.. We should see what jQuery UI guys say about this.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me, but the following variation did:

```
$("input.date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
            $('.date').datepicker('show');
        }, this), 10);
    }
});
```