# Datepicker not showing after onselected

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
<form action="" class="test-form">  
  <input type="text" name="start">  
  <input type="text" name="end"> 
</form>

$('input[name=start]').datepicker({
  onSelect: function () {
    var $thisEnd = $(this).closest('.test-form').find('input[name=end]');
      $thisEnd.datepicker();
      $thisEnd.datepicker('show');
    }
});
$('input[name=end]').datepicker();
```

When selected datepicker start, datepicker end open and at once close. I don't no why.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076304/jquery-datepicker-only-works-once-and-is-not-shown-the-second-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI datepicker closes on next().focus()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218331/jquery-ui-datepicker-closes-on-next-focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Use `setTimeout()` for auto open datepicker of end date:

```js
$('input[name=end]').datepicker();

$('input[name=start]').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,  // This enable you to close the picker
    onSelect: function () { 
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('input[name="end"]').focus();
      }, 10);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<form action="" class="test-form">  
  <input type="text" name="start">  
  <input type="text" name="end"> 
</form>
```